# Vue.js: How to show loading statement instead of white page before application loads

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

When a new Vue.js page is opened, a white page appears for a while until the whole application loads.
I tried many times to put the loading statement first with the traditional way, but the problem is that even the loading statement needs a while to load and appear, to replace the white page.

```
<div id="app">
    <template>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <navbar></navbar>

      <v-content class="mx-sm-12 mt-8 mx-1">
        <router-view />
      </v-content>
    </v-app>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import navbar from "./components/navbar";

export default {
  components: {
    navbar
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: How do you add your traditional  way o?

Comment: I'd say that you should be using lazy loading for your modules so that it doesn't take any time to load the app, thus rendering the loading statement obsolete because no-one would see it.

Comment: Hi Ahmed!
Did you solve your problem?
I am trying to add animation to my Vue application during the first initial loading.
I can see the image but the animation doesn't work. Would you like to tell me some tips for this problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your html will be downloaded and render first. you should have your loading in the index.html.

After the JS (Vue built file) downloaded it will replace the `<div id="app"></div>` in your index.html.

I solved this loading by having my index.html like this:

```
<html>
<head>
   ...
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <div id="loading__container">
       <div>some animation and text to indicate loading...</div>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
#loading__container {
    // animation style
}
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var loading = document. getElementById("loading__container")
    // ... do things with the loading container
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, this is what I am looking for

Comment: Hi Chop! I am trying to add animation to my Vue application during the first initial loading. I can see the image but the animation doesn't work. Would you like to tell me some tips for this problem?

Answer (score 10):

HTML

`<div id="app"  v-cloak></div>`

CSS: Add following style into the CSS file

`[v-cloak] > * { display:none }
 [v-cloak]::before { content: "Loading…" }`

You can use animated gif instead of 'loading' text.

Comment: perfect! i was looking for this solution!!

Comment: Adding a animation to the index.html app id element is a good idea, simply putting <progress></progress> will show a progress bar without any css.  However when vue instance is created and the js kicks in, thepage will again turn blank as it parses the router file, main.js app.vue etc.. this is where you may need a second animation. not sure yet how to solve this one.